# Apache mod_proxy HTTP tracing

Tags: apache-2.2

Can mod_proxy be configured to write all HTTP traffic to a log file, including request and response headers and body?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so, though doing so would be a trivial task for `tcpdump`.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on ErikA's answer:

A simple way of doing this is to capture all traffic on port 80 to a file:

```
tcpdump -w /tmp/packets port 80
```

And then use "strings" to extract the text content of the packets:

```
strings /tmp/packets
```

This will include some garbage but will generally get you what you need.  You can also use the "Follow TCP Stream" feature in Wireshark to get a cleaner version of the same thing.

Life is a little more difficult if you're working with SSL traffic.  A typical solution would be to use stunnel to intercept the SSL traffic and then proxy it to your web server over the loopback interface; this lets you capture the unencrypted traffic.